# Defining function using if-statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, if-statement, printing

```
def roots4(a,b,c,d):
    d = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if a != 0 and d == 0:
        roots4(a,b,c,d) 
        x = -b/ (2*a)
    if a != 0 and d > 0:
        roots4(a,b,c,d)
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a
    if a != 0 and d < 0:
        roots4(a,b,c,d)
        xre = (-b) / (2*a)   
        xim = (math.sqrt(d))/ (2*a)
        print x1  = xre + ixim
        strx1 = "x2 = %6.2f + i %6.2f" %(xre, xim)
        print strx1
```

This is part of my code for a project. What I'm trying to do is define `roots4(a,b,c,d)`. For example,  in the case that `a != 0 and d == 0` then `roots4(a,b,c,d)` shall then go to to finding `x` by solving equation `x = -b/ (2*a)`. And so on... I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any tips?

Comment: Why the recursive calls? What is the desired effect, printing the solutions or returning them?

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass d as parameter

Comment: What do you do if `a == 0`? What do you mean by solving equation "x = -b/ (2*a)" (is there still really any equation to solve?)

Comment: Why are you passing *d*  as a parameter if you don't use it? AFAIK parameters are not passed as references but as copies.

Comment: Also, what is expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments and jimmy's answer, there's no need for recursive calls.

Here's an example of how you could correct it (adapt it the way you like):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math


def roots4(a, b, c):
    """Prints the solutions of ax² + bx + c = 0, if a != 0"""
    if a == 0:
        print 'This function is meant to solve a 2d degree equation, '\
            'not a 1st degree one.'
    else:
        d = b * b - 4 * a * c
        solutions = []
        if d == 0:
            solutions = [str(-b / (2 * a))]
        elif d > 0:
            solutions = [str((-b + math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a),
                         str((-b - math.sqrt(d)) / 2.0 / a)]
        elif d < 0:
            xre = str((-b) / (2 * a))
            xim = str((math.sqrt(-d)) / (2 * a))
            solutions = [xre + " + i" + xim,
                         xre + " - i" + xim]

        print "\nEquation is: {}x² + {}x + {} = 0".format(a, b, c)

        if len(solutions) == 1:
            print "There's only one solution: " + solutions[0]
        else:
            print "Solutions are: " + " and ".join(solutions)

roots = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
         (0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
         (0.0, 2.0, 4.0),
         (1.0, 2.0, 1.0),
         (1.0, -5.0, 6.0),
         (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)]

for r in roots:
    roots4(*r)
```

Output:

```
$ ./test_script2.py
This function is meant to solve a 2d degree equation, not a 1st degree one.
This function is meant to solve a 2d degree equation, not a 1st degree one.
This function is meant to solve a 2d degree equation, not a 1st degree one.

Equation is: 1.0x² + 2.0x + 1.0 = 0
There's only one solution: -1.0

Equation is: 1.0x² + -5.0x + 6.0 = 0
Solutions are: 3.0 and 2.0

Equation is: 1.0x² + 2.0x + 3.0 = 0
Solutions are: -1.0 + i1.41421356237 and -1.0 - i1.41421356237
```

Comment: I'm doing something exactly like this! Yes! Except my roots are:

Comment: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
 (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
 (0.0, 2.0, 4.0)
 (1.0, 2.0, 1.0)
 (1.0, -5.0, 6.0)
 (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

Comment: Do you mean you get the roots as tuples?

Comment: So the whole point is to extract these roots from a .txt file that I made and then have the output placed into another  outfile .txt file. Thats the whole premise.

Comment: @JesusAnaya I've included the tuples you gave in a list. Removed the exception otherwise you would only get the exception from start; I replaced it with a string. Now, I guess reading the roots from a .txt file and save results in another one is another question. It's not yet possible to answer it as you have not provided the file content, neither what you exactly expect in the output file. Try to solve this by yourself and ask another question if you can't solve it.

Comment: Glad I could help! You might consider accepting my answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

you probably stacked with

```
    ...
            roots4(a,b,c,d)
    ...
```

this causes an infinite loop

firstly, why do you need a recursion call? what's `d` parameter for?

secondly, what is `ixim`? should it be something like `xim * 1j`?
what do you expect from `print x1  = xre + ixim`?

if you want print only in case when `d < 0` this will be fine

```
    from math import sqrt


    def roots4(a,b,c):
        if a != 0.:
            x_left = -b/(2*a)

            d = b * b - 4 * a * c
            if d == 0.:
                x_right = 0.
            elif d > 0.:
                x_right = sqrt(d) / (2 * a)
            else:
                xim = sqrt(-d) / (2 * a)
                strx1 = "x1 = %6.2f + i %6.2f" %(x_left, xim)
                print strx1
                strx2 = "x2 = %6.2f - i %6.2f" %(x_left, xim)
                print strx2
                x_right = xim * 1j
            x1 = x_left + x_right
            x2 = x_left - x_right
        else:
            raise ValueError("incorrect leading coefficient in given square equation")
```

Comment: if you want to return your `x1, x2` you should write something like `return x1, x2` right after their calculation

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you have made an infinite loop with your recursive functions. As it looks now you will never do any calculations apart from

```
d = b * b - 4 * a * c
```

over and over again.

Consider the program flow. Each time you reach

```
roots4(a,b,c,d)
```

you will end up in the top again.